# MySQL delete rows inserted by mistake

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with data sorted by date since 2016. Every week, I would insert new rows (from data in recent dates) to the table. I just accidentally inserted data from mid Sept to mid Oct to the table.

I want to delete the last 100 rows from the table. However, if I use the code

```
    delete from myTable
    limit 100 rows
```

It only delete the first 100 rows. I couldn't sort the data as if I sort the data by date, I would delete the 100 recent rows, not the 100 rows that I accidentally inserted.

I also couldn't use SELECT to find the incorrect ones because if I use SELECT, I would select the data that I inserted in Oct. Our data is live so the data that I inserted in Oct is different from the one I just inserted. The only things that they share are IDs and date. The values are different. For example, you can imagine that it is the sale balance per Customer ID. In Oct, the balance could be $100 but if I export the data now, the balance would be different.

Thank you,
H

Comment: Use a WHERE clause to isolate the last hundred rows.

Comment: you should use where primary key > x and primary key <= y with x being the last good id value and y being the last bad id value assuming you have an auto increment id on the table

Comment: Just for the safe sake, you always perform a `SELECT` to make sure what you querying is what you want to delete!

Comment: First write a SELECT statement that identifies and returns the set of rows you want to delete. After that is tested, turn it into a DELETE statement.

Comment: Go to your backups and restore your database up to the point of your bad insertion of data.

Comment: The problem with SELECT is that if I use that I would select the old correct data and the newly inserted incorrect data. And my data is live so these old correct data and incorrect data are different.

Comment: To me, your not giving a clear picture that you can actually select the rows you inserted by mistake.

Comment: A 'date_entered' or other column that was populated with now() either by script or by default would prevent this from happening.  You might have to go through your list of inserted by error rows, locate and delete them one by one.  Effective table design would prevent this issue in the future...kinda screwed by design here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `order by`.  For instance, if you have an auto-incrementing id:

```
delete t from myTable t
order by id desc
limit 100 rows;
```

Comment: the ids are set by tech ppl and they are random.

Comment: @HaiVuNgoc: But do you have ANY way of uniquely identifying those bad 100 rows?